# Disable NLA on client side

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services

I already disabled NLA on the Terminal Service of Windows 2008 server, that now `rdesktop` connects to the console directly,

But from a Windows 7 client, it still asks me to populate the password prior to logon.

Any ideas?

P.S: `mstsc /v:servername /console /admin` doesn't work, it still asks for password

Comment: Why are you using both switches /console and /admin? /Console is no longer support on W2k8. [See more details](http://www.microsoftnow.com/2008/01/no-more-mstscexe-console.html).
Try "mstsc /v:servername /admin" instead.

Comment: Why disable NLA in the first place?

Comment: @ChrisS we run RSA SecureID with Terminal Service, if NLA is running, the user would be prompt for password twice, once before connecting to the console; once when login. So, need to get rid of NLA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an .rdp file for the connection, and specify enablecredsspsupport:i:0 in the rdp file.

https://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2010/12/16/xp-clients-credssp-sso-connection-broker-and-other-animals.aspx